# big integer is displaying with scientific notation in excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am exporting mysql data into excel sheet by using php like below.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
?>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr>
    <th class="excel_style">Order Type</th>
    <th class="excel_style">Order Number</th>
    <th class="excel_style">EAN</th>
    <th class="excel_style">Article #</th>
</tr>
<?php
// mysqli query comes here
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){?>
<td><?php echo $result['order_type'] ;?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['order_number'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['EAN'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $result['article_number'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Every thing works fine, but after generating excel report in EAN and Article # column the values are displaying like scientific notation, like below.
`4.04623E+12 but the original value is - 4046228026756`. So when user opens excel sheet the related column should display with original value. How can I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is there any way to tell to excel the data type of the cell is type String. Some thing like below
`$excel1->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueExplicit('C'.$k, $row['EAN'],PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING)`

Comment: try to open exported file in notepad and check if format is changed? or try to export in CSV

Comment: Exporting to .csv instead of .xls will fix your issue as mentioned above.

Comment: MS word will display numbers in scientific notation when there's isn't enough display space for all the content try to drag the column edge over for more space and check now if it's still the same.

Comment: @Bleach, I have some table format styles are there . When I change to .csv , and open then  I am able to see complete html data like <table><tr><td>123</td></tr></table>. I need this only in excel

Comment: I have never found a way around this exporting to excel. If you create an empty excel file and preeformat the columns as text, then have ypur script write to the file, instead of creating a new one, that would work.